# [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined in Vue CLI 4

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli

I'm trying to import v-movable (https://github.com/thewebkid/v-movable) in a component inside my Vue app created with Vue CLI 4, but I keep getting the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

  found in

    ---> <Movable>
      <Intro>
        <App> at src/App.vue
          <Root>
```

Currently my main.js file looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

And my Intro.vue component file looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="intro">
    <div class="guideline">
      <div class="circle start-circle"></div>
      <movable class="circle end-circle">
        <IconSlideUp id="icon-slide-up" />
        <span class="label">Slide</span>
      </movable>
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import IconSlideUp from '@/assets/icon-slide-up.svg'
import movable from 'v-movable'

export default {
  name: 'Intro',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  components: {
    IconSlideUp,
    movable
  },
  methods: {
    
  }
}
</script>


<style scoped lang="scss">
...
</style>
```

Do I need to globally register movable in my main.js? How would I go about doing that? Any help would be very much appreciated, and please do let me know if there's any other information I can/should provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project's Github demo, there is a component import, which can be done in a SFC this way:

```js
import movable from './components/movable';
```

<sup>https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-cartwright-yvis1</sup>

You are using the plugin installation, but doing it inside of a component instead of *main.js*, and it's missing `Vue.use`.  Remove the import from your component and change *main.js*:

*main.js*

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue';
import movable from 'v-movable';

Vue.use(movable);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

Comment: Result is the same. I'm installing v-movable via npm, which is why I'm importing it that way, as stated in the documentation (http://thewebkid.com/modules/v-movable).

Comment: Since you don't want to import the component (the result is not the same if you do it correctly-- you can see that from the demo), I've edited to explain what's wrong with your plugin installation.  Both are installed via npm, that's not the issue, it's that there are 2 options:  plugin installation or component import

Comment: How did the fixed plugin installation work out for you?

Comment: The key was to import it as a component rather than using the plugin installation. Thanks for the help!